# How to specify the python path for pip?

Tags: ubuntu, python, pip

With pip installed, I am trying to install matplotlib in Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS.
I got the following error when executing "sudo pip install matplotlib"
[image]

I guess this is because the python version is too old (2.7.3), So I follow this discussion, [How to install the latest Python version on Debian separately or upgrade?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110014/how-to-install-the-latest-python-version-on-debian-separately-or-upgrade), to build the latest 2.7.11 in /opt/python/.

My question is how to specify the newer version of python when installing matplotlib through pip?

Or should I just use "easy_install", which is not recommended by other people?

Thank you for precious time on my question.

Answer (score 1):

Pip is bundled with Python 2.7.11 (they started adding it in 2.7.9 and 3.4), so you can use an included module to generate a short `pip` script:

```
$ /opt/python/bin/python -m ensurepip
```

That will make `/opt/python/bin/pip`, which has a shebang line pointing at `/opt/python/bin/python`, so you can run it when you want a `pip` that's associated with that particular Python installation.

If you're running an older Python, you can download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and pass it to the Python you want to install it under:

```
$ wget 'https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py'
$ /opt/python/bin/python ./get-pip.py
```

This will generate the same `pip` scripts. See the [pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Using the following worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

The [following page](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html) also has more information about installing matplotlib.

Comment: That works for this particular case, but the question is how to control which version of Python is used when running pip

Comment: -1 because you just state another way without giving an answer why it works, what it does, what the difference is (yes, there is a huge difference between the two approaches)